# Makefile: Circular - Dependency dropped

Tags: makefile, circular-dependency

I have designed a Makefile that compiles all the .c files individually and produces a .o respectively (I think this happens Implicitly and works perfectly fine).

The executable (.out) is not being generated from the .o files.

**Makefile:**

```
TARGET = all.out
OBJS = file1.o file2.o file3.o
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
all : $(TARGET)
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
#   gcc $^ -o $@
run : $(TARGET)
    ./$<
clean :
    rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)
```

**Output:**

```
$ make 
make: Circular all.out <- all dependency dropped.
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file1.o file1.c
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file2.o file2.c
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file3.o file3.c
cp file1.o all.out
```

**Note:** The Makefile works perfectly and produces the perfect results if the line no. 7 present in it is uncommented.

line no. 7:

```
#   gcc $^ -o $@
```

**Output when line no. 7 is uncommented (Works perfectly as intended):**

```
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file1.o file1.c
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file2.o file2.c
gcc -g -Wall    -c -o file3.o file3.c
gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o -o a.out
```

I am new to Makefiles.

**Queries:**

1. why does commenting line no. 7 causing this issue and uncommenting it works perfectly?
2. What is **cp** in the first output when line no.7 was commented?
3. What does **circular - dependency dropped** mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain how you are seeing the problem you showed to us.  Either what you wrote above is not actually what you're using, or you have a buggy version of GNU make.  I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

But, I'm sure it's related to this: GNU make has a built-in rule that knows how to build an `xx.out` file from a file `xx` for any `xx`:

```
# make -p -f/dev/null
  ...
%.out: %
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        @rm -f $@
        cp $< $@
```

If you comment out your own recipe as an explicit rule, then make will search for one among the pattern rules it knows about and it will find this built-in pattern rule.

However this rule *shouldn't* match based on what you've shown us: in order for it to match with a target of `a.out`, make would have to find or know how to build a target `a` and that doesn't seem to be available.  Also, knowing how to build `a` would show a circular dependency on `a.out`.

If your makefile was:

```
TARGET = all.out
```

THEN it would all make perfect sense because you would have:

```
all : all.out
all.out : file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

and after the implicit rule match `%.out: %` it would expand like this:

```
all : all.out
all.out : all file1.o file2.o file3.o
        @rm -f all.out
        cp all all.out
```

So I assume that when you copied the output into your question you changed it: best to not do that.  You should post exactly the problem you have (and verify you still have the problem with what you posted).

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, Apologies for the slight mods in files. I have edited the file names as they were too long. Also, I made all.out to a.out assuming to have a better readability. I have edited it back to normal. Based on your answer, when the line no. 7 is commented & the TARGET = all.out, I get the "Circular - Dependency dropped" error. When the line no. 7  is still commented & the TARGET = a.out it only builds the .o files from .c files. Can you help me with this???? (NOTE: edited the names back to normal)

Comment: Also, When the TARGET = a.out or TARGET = all.out and line no. 7 is uncommented, It works well and doesn't show any Circulare dependency error!!

Comment: Yes, exactly.  All of that behavior is _precisely_ what I'd expect and what I explained in my answer.  Can you describe which part of my answer wasn't clear or what you didn't understand about it?

Comment: Got the logic. Thank you! Observations and Inferences:                                                                                          1. target name (all) and dependency (all.out) name should not be same when using implicit rule. 2. Explicit rule (line no. 7) needs to be specified when the target (all) and dependency (all.out) have the same name to avoid "Circular dependency dropped" error as shown in the expansion of  the implicit rule (all : all.out and all.out : all). 3. If target (all) and dependency (a.out) names are different, Implicit rule cannot be applied. Are these correct?

Comment: 3 is correct.  The other two are not quite accurate.  You have to think about what your goal is in removing the recipe to build `all.out`.  If you don't have a recipe (not an explicit rule), then make will try to find a recipe by using an implicit rule.  What is it that you actually want make to do in this case?  What is your intent behind removing that recipe?

Comment: My intent on the design is to let Make build everything (from %,c to %.o and *.o to all.out) using implicit rules. Hence I was trying out the above. Can you help me with how the point 1 and 2 in my previous comment are not quite accurate as I was able to understand only those from your answer :(

Comment: If you want an implicit rule for your target `all.out` you need to create one yourself.  Make doesn't have any built-in implicit rule that will create a file `%.out` by linking a program from some random set of object files.  If you make your own implicit rule, that will take precedence over the built-in rule for copying `.out` files and you won't have these problems.

Comment: For your (1) I don't know what you mean by a target name and dependency should "not be the same"; certainly you can't create a target "foo" that depends on itself ("foo") but in that same sentence you list "all" and "all.out", which are not the same of course.  It's fine to have a target `foo` that depends on a prerequisite `bar`, _AS LONG AS_ you don't also define a target `bar` that depends on a prerequisite `foo`.  That's a circular dependency.

Comment: For your (2) again I don't know what you mean by "the same name" since `all` and `all.out` obviously are not the same name.  You can't have a circular dependency anywhere in your makefile, regardless of whether you are using explicit or implicit rules: it doesn't matter.  A makefile is parsed into a directed **acyclic** graph: a circular dependency is a cycle in the graph and is illegal (in make).

Comment: I was able to understand with a bit (1 day) of digging in to this. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Hi Again @MadScientist, I was able to understand why "all : all.out" was throwing the circular dependency error but can you help me with why "all : a.out" just builds the .o files and stops there when line no. 7 is commented??? looking at your explanation when implicit rule expansion happens  "all : a.out", "a.out : a file1.o file2.o file3.o", "@rm-f a.out" and "cp $< $@" should happen. But this is not happening. Can you help me with this?? It is not showing circular dependency error in this case!!

Comment: Make doesn't know how to build a `a.out` file from a file named `file1.o`.  Once you comment out the recipe that tells make how to build it, make can't find any way to build the target `a.out`.  So it doesn't try to build it.  The reason the implicit rule doesn't match is that the implicit rule matches any file `xxx.out` that can be built from `xxx` for any string `xxx`.  When your target was `all.out` and the other target was `all`, they matched because `all` == `all`.  When your target is `a.out` and the other target is `all` they don't match because `a` != `all`.